# How can we remove an items from itext7 List using c#?

Tags: itext7

I have one listobj which is `Itext7` list

```
List listd = new List();
```

i want to remove the items from the above `listd` object.

I have tried but i was unable to find.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: First: Welcome to Stackoverflow.
Its a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do here. What programming language are you using? What is the _Itext7_ list?

Comment: @JPVenson we are using c# only

iText 7 is a PDF software development platform - written in Java and .NET - that allows you to integrate PDF functionalities within your applications, processes and products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `AbstractElement` instances, including `List`, have `getChildren()` method. It gives you the list (collection) containing children of that instance. You can access that list directly and remove any child you want to.

E.g. if you execute this code:

```
List list = new List().add("One").add("Two").add("Three");
list.getChildren().remove(1);
```

Then you would end up with two items in the list, the first one ("One") and last one ("Three").

The code is for Java but if you are using C# then you should just adapt the part interacting with the `IList` interface which should be straightforward.